# Copy a single database from one RDS instance (Postgres) to another

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump

I have 2 RDS instances with Postgres.
I need to transfer one of the databases from RDS instance A to RDS instance B.
How am I supposed to do it, if pg_dump is not accessible outside a bash shell and you can't access bash shell from an RDS instance?

Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to access the bash shell from RDS. Do you mean you can't access RDS from the bash shell? How exactly do you access RDS then? I actually did this a few days ago using CodeBuild - I made it install postgres locally (in the codebuild environment), then using pg_dump and psql, I made it dump the database from one rds and restored it straight into the other. Not sure whether this is an option for you.

Comment: I mean I connect to RDS from my machine via psql -h xxx -U xx, but since RDS is an isolated database env, I end up in psql shell where you can't use pg_dump. Is there any other way to copy a db from RDS to another RDS?

Comment: If you can run `psql`, then you can run `pg_dump`. They take similar input parameters. They both run separately on the command line.